# The right order of shifting bits in c

Tags: c, bit-shift

What is the difference and why are there **3**(???) different results?

```
signed char b;
b = 66 << 2 >> 8;
fprintf(stdout, "%d\n", b);
```

Output: "1"

```
signed char b;
b = 66 << 2;
b = b >> 8;
fprintf(stdout, "%d\n", b);
```

Output: "0"

```
signed char b;
b = 2 >> 8;
b = 66 << b;
fprintf(stdout, "%d\n", b);
```

Output: "66"

thanks for help!

Comment: Not directly related to your question, but you should always perform shifts on unsigned types, as otherwise the result of overflow is undefined.

Comment: If you split one expression into multiple, it is the same effect as using brackets.

Comment: @Gerhardh Only if you use the correct (promoted) types, which the code here doesn't do.

Comment: @interjay True, I missed that part. My point was that brackets are known to change the result. And so is splitting the operations in multiple statements. There is no reason to expect same result for each case.

Answer (score 3):

```
signed char b = 66 << 2 >> 8;
```

Here, `66 << 2` becomes a `signed int` 264 (`signed int` because it is an intermediate result), which is shifted `>> 8`, which becomes 1.

```
signed char b = 66 << 2;
```

Here, the 264 (same as above) is "pressed" into a `signed char`, turning it to 8. Applying `>> 8` here results in 0.

Well, and your 3rd example, `2 >> 8` is obvously 0, so the `66` is left unchanged.